# How to use Node.js Express function in html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to use Node.js express function in html file (When someone open the site so it will run node.js function), How am i able to do that?

Comment: Send a request to the server with node.js

Answer (score 1):

Express isn't a function, it is a module for running a web server.

The order of events is:

- You write a program using Express and run it with Node.js
- The program then listens for an HTTP request
- You make an HTTP request (typically with a web browser) to that server (e.g. `http://example.com/your.html`)
- Express uses its routing logic to work out which of your functions to run
- That function calls a method of the response object to determine which content to send back to the browser

Comment: I know but i don't know how to run a code when the page opens

Comment: @CheapsiT — https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html